# iChat showing contacts from people I've emailed once

Tags: messages, ichat

In my iChat (now Messages?) buddy list I have a lot of buddies that are not buddies but people I've emailed once. It used to not do this. Is there a way to go back to that previous list?

Comment: Are you syncing contacts with Google or Yahoo as well as iCloud?

Comment: I have two accounts. The first is my personal Google and the second is Google through our work. I think it's called Google Apps or Google email for business, if that makes sense?

Comment: It does, well, the thing is, Google adds every person you reply to, to your contacts once you reply to them. So then your account brings them back to your contacts, buddies, etc. It's a PITA.